# No route found for "GET /" on adminpage

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

After moving to a different server, the backend of my Prestashop shows me an Error 500. Frontend works fine.

I added `var_dump($rnfe->getMessage());` on try/catch block in the admin/index.php:

```
try {   
   $response = $kernel->handle($request, HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, false);
   $response->send();
   $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
} catch (NotFoundHttpException $rnfe) {
    var_dump($rnfe->getMessage());
```

And i get this message:

`string(26) "No route found for "GET /""`

Any idea how to fix this or where i can start to search?

Comment: do you have renamed the admin folder, or put the root of prestashop in a subfolder?

Comment: no i did not rename the admin folder and yes the shop is in a subfolder {root}/shop/

Comment: check into root folder the .htaccess  file and add the subfolder name in RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/subfolder], if you are not sure of what are you doing you have to edit a couple of option in configuration table into phpmyadmin

Comment: sorry i was wrong. I forgot to mention that the prestashop is running on a subdomain which is pointing to the subfolder /shop/, so the subfolder is the root of this domain.

Comment: ok, remove all the content from /var/cache/ and try again

Comment: there is no "var/cache" folder. maybe because i have the version 1.7.1 of prestashop. I have deleted the content of "app/cache/prod", /shop/cache/smarty/cache" and "/shop/cache/smarty/compile" instead but it still does not work.

Comment: yes /var/cache/ intoduced in 1.7.5, what apache error log says about your 500?

Comment: the last thing that i can think about is to check 2 option values in DB within ps_configuration table. they are PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and  PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL this option should contain the domain name (thirdlevel.domain.com)  in your case

Comment: did you try to "clear" your htaccess by going into shop parameters>traffic & seo, in the block "set up urls" set friendly url to false and save ?

Comment: I solved the Problem! My new server has PHP7.2, but this Prestashop version only runs with PHP <= 7.1. But its seems to affect the Backend only... Still thanks for the help!